# How to make a textarea in which the text can be formatted?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I make a textarea's format editable, such as the textareas on this site, by using javascript or php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a 3rd party plugin rather than rolling your own.
A quick google reveals the follwoing for jQuery : http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/rich-text-editor